# Down Sampling a long vector based on average

Tags: python

**Problem:**

I have a long vector which I want to downsample. 
By downsampling I mean take the long vector and shorten it by averaging parts of it.

I'm using *Python (2.7)*

For example I have a mono audio file which was recorded at `44,100 Hz`.
The recording is `10 seconds` long, providing a vector of `length 441,000`.

Say I want to downsample it to `8KHz`. The output vector should be `80,000 long`.

Of course, much of information will be lost by downsampling.

**Suggested solution:**

The Sample rates ratio is:

```
R = 44100 / 8000 = 5.5125
```

So, I would like to take every `5.5125` samples of the original vector and average it into a single number.

- Is there a library function which does this (i.e. from Numpy, statistics, etc. Python libraries)?
- If not, can you recommend a neat way to run this? How can I average a non-integer index (`5.5125`)?
- How can I "break" the original vector into smaller parts of `5.5125` size in a neat way?

Comment: http://signalsprocessed.blogspot.com/2016/08/audio-resampling-in-python.html

Comment: as mentioned resampling can be tricky and can introduce unnecesary noise. So it is best to consult a DSP book on algorithms and/or use/rely on scipy and similar libs

Comment: Why not just resample 8820 Hz which is a  factor of 5?